# Json parse in Express app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am creating a small application to in order to test a larger application I am building. This is reading from a CSV file and attempting to POST that data to my API endpoint (this is being done to send a large dataset over time).

Everything works perfectly well with Postman, but I am having trouble getting node to play nice. A sample json object I am posting looks like this

```
{ 
    meta: 
      [ 'array','of','headers'],
    data: [
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [7,8,9]]
}
```

When I receive the data in express, it comes through as `meta=[array, of, headers], data=[0=1, 1=2, 2=3, 0=4, 1=5, 2=6, 0=7, 1=8, 2=9]`

I assume this is something to do with the way I am sending my JSON (as I said, this renders fine from Postman).
I am stringifying the data before it's sent, setting headers to 

`"Content-type":"application/json"` and setting the `"content-length".`

After vanilla http request I tried using [request-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-json), but I am getting the same result.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the `body-parser` in express?

Comment: Yes I am, I should have mentioned that. Everything works perfectly well when Postman sends the data

Comment: When you say everything works well when postman sends the data, does that mean the server is able to interpret the javascript as expected?  And this server may or may not be in node, but it doesn't matter, because the issue is with sending the request in node.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the application can receive and interpret the data as intended when I send from postman. Both are node applications. On the client side I am posting data with request-json as 
var client = request.createClient('http://localhost:3000/');
    client.post('api/v1/run', item, function(err, res, body) {
        return console.log(res.statusCode);
    });

and the response I posted above is the result of req.body on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the data was in fact being transferred properly, it was the fact that I was sending strings that led me to believe that there were errors here.

Comment: Glad you got it figured our Ronan!